# a problem involving a function, power class and indexed family of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help with the proof of the following Exercise 6.14 in J. D. Monk's *Introduction to Set Theory* (p.57). Here is the problem.

---

Given a set $A$ and a function $\boldsymbol{F}:\mathtt{S}A\rightarrow\mathtt{S}A$ s.t. $\boldsymbol{F}C\cap D=\varnothing$ iff $C\cap\boldsymbol{F}D=\varnothing$, $\forall C,D\in\mathtt{S}A$. If $\left\langle \boldsymbol{B}_{i}:i\in I\right\rangle$ is an indexed family of members of $\mathtt{S}A$, where $I$ is a set, show that $\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)=\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}$.

(Here $\mathtt{S}A=\left\{ X:X\subseteq A\right\}$, the power class of $A$.)

---

Solution:

(i) To show $\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}$. We use contradiction.

Let $u\in\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)$ and suppose $u\notin\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}$.

Now, $u\notin\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}$ implies that $u\notin\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{j}$, $\exists j\in I$.

Thus, $\left\{ u\right\} \cap\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{j}=\varnothing$.

Therefore, by the assumption on $\boldsymbol{F}$, we have $\boldsymbol{F}\left\{ u\right\} \cap\boldsymbol{B}_{j}=\varnothing$.

But, since $\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\subseteq\boldsymbol{B}_{j}$, this implies $\boldsymbol{F}\left\{ u\right\} \cap\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right]=\varnothing$.

Therefore, by assumption on $\boldsymbol{F}$, we have $\left\{ u\right\} \cap\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)=\varnothing$.

But this implies $u\notin\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)$, a contradiction.

(ii) To show $\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)\supseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}$. I'm trying to use contradiction here too.

Let $u\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}$ and suppose $u\notin\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)$.

Now, $u\notin\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)$ implies $\left\{ u\right\} \cap\boldsymbol{F}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)=\varnothing$.

So, by the assumption on $\boldsymbol{F}$, we have $\boldsymbol{F}\left\{ u\right\} \cap\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)=\varnothing$.

But this one, $\boldsymbol{F}\left\{ u\right\} \cap\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}\right)=\varnothing$, does not imply $\boldsymbol{F}\left\{ u\right\} \cap\boldsymbol{B}_{j}=\varnothing$, for some $j\in I$. I was working on trying to get that, so I can go on like this:

$\Longrightarrow$ $\left\{ u\right\} \cap\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{j}=\varnothing$, by assumption on $\boldsymbol{F}$.

$\Longrightarrow$ $u\notin\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{j}$, for this $j\in I$.

$\Longrightarrow$ $u\notin\bigcap_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{F}\boldsymbol{B}_{i}=\varnothing$, a contradiction.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While (i) is true, and in fact $F(X)\subseteq F(Y)$ whenever $X\subseteq Y$, (ii) is false.

Consider any set $A$ with at least two elements. Define $F:P(A)\to P(A)$ (I can't bring myself to use Monk's notation for the powerset) by
$$F(X)=\begin{cases}
\emptyset&\text{if }X=\emptyset\\
A&\text{if }X\ne\emptyset
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$F(X)\cap Y=\emptyset\iff X\cap F(Y)=\emptyset$$
Indeed, suppose $F(X)\cap Y=\emptyset$. If $X=\emptyset$, then $X\cap F(Y)=\emptyset$. If $X\ne\emptyset$, then $F(X)=A$, so
$$Y=A\cap Y=F(X)\cap Y=\emptyset$$
by assumption, so $F(Y)=\emptyset$, and $X\cap F(Y)=\emptyset$. Similarly for the converse.

However, if $X$ and $Y$ are any two nonempty disjoint subsets of $A$, then
$$F(X\cap Y)=F(\emptyset)=\emptyset$$
while
$$F(X)\cap F(Y)=A\cap A=A\ne\emptyset$$
so
$$F(X)\cap F(Y)\not\subseteq F(X\cap Y)$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, great one! Been thinking about this since I posted it. I've actually begun to think that it (ii) is actually false, but just to put my mind at ease.. i've never thought about finding a counter example like this.

Comment: Trying to construct a counter-example to any claim that "every $x$ with property $P$ has property $Q$" can be a helpful way of approaching a problem. If the claim is false, it's usually the best way to show that, and if the claim is true, the things which frustrate the attempts to create the counter-example can highlight important things which will end up in a proof.

Comment: True. It's just kinda intimidating in this case because the `natural' counterexample involves arbitrarily many sets. it's also kinda disheartening because i've been thinking about proving this for like 2 days, even seeing my notes in dreams, and here is a very simple conter example. hahah

Comment: @A.David That's actually very normal in math, nothing to be discouraged by. Just think it's not as bad as Cantor going back and forth on CH before folks later discovered it to be independent of ZFC. :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now I can move on to next section on equivalence relations. :D Im trying to answer all exercises in the book. Im obsessive that way.

Comment: @A.David No problem. By the way, if you are satisfied with an answer, please consider "accepting" it. This benefits the person who answered and takes the question off the unanswered list on the site.

Comment: oh sure. i didnt know i could do that. i'm new to this forum.